# Connecting IBM Mobile App Builder to GoogleSheets bluemix-mobile-services

Tags: oauth-2.0, ibm-cloud, ibm-mobile-services

I am trying to access Google Sheets with the IBM Bluemix Mobile App Builder tool and I think something isn't working with the OAuth. I understand that the tool is currently experimental, but here is what happens. I select Google Sheet as a data source, I give it the name of a Google Sheet that exists in my Google account called "TeamsGoogle". The Oauth2 screen comes up asking "IBM Mobile App Builder would like to: Have offline access." I select Allow and then it returns to Mobile App Builder and has a message of "We couldn't find any data in your worksheet! "

Comment: I'm currently looking into this.

Comment: It's a known issue and currently being worked on.

Answer (score 0):

We've just launched the new Bluemix Mobile dashboard, and this bug has been fixed.

Comment: Yes this has been fixed Thank You.  I am having a similar problem with the Microsoft Excel Spreadsheets online, So not sure if there is a similar problem with that one.